# Is it OK to add a Notification area/widget on a dashboard where there is already a notification icon on the header?

Tags: usability, dashboard

I'm building the dashboard page for a complex system. The system has a notification icon that is on the header and can be seen from all pages. the user needs to mouse over or click on the icon to actually see the notifications.

The notifications are important events and things that the user needs to know and respond to.

I am considering whether I should create a Notification panel that will be visible only on the dashboard page so when the user enters the system they will immediately see what he needs to do.

Do you think this is redundant?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not redundant, and may be expected.**

If your app's header notification icon requires some action (mouse click, hover etc), it may be wise to have this information automatically expanded on the home page of the dashboard.

Many users will expect the dashboard to be the primary page to triage and act on notifications.

You can see this pattern in action here on StackExchange:

- The icons in the upper right will change to indicate new activity.
- You can click this icon to see more detail while remaining on the page.
- You can visit your user profile page, where you will see the full detail of all interactions, which will include any new notifications.